# Windows 2008 - printer redirection excludes

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, remote-desktop-services

Anyone know if theres a way to exclude certain redirected printer queues from being created under windows 2008.

It seems to be all or nothing and I would like to be able to just exclude certain printers which show up all over the place and which just are never going to be used on this server.

for example
  "PDF Creator"
  "XPS*"
  The printer which is on the local subnet and which already exists on the terminal server

With one or two users this isn't a problem, but once you have 50+ the number of queues multiplies.

Ian

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately, no. Its an all or nothing system. It seems a bit lacking in foresight on microsofts part. It would be something incredibly easy to do using, say, a regex expression for those to include or excluse.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows 2008 ADMX templates you can configure a GPO to only redirect the default client printer.

Other than that I don't think it's possible to selectively redirect printers.

Comment: What I wanted to do was exclude some of the dozens of printer queues which appear and which I know users do not need remapped. Citrix can do this via a text file. Redirecting only the default printer would not work in my case.

thanks anyway.